# Why would a republic still have the word Principality or Kingdom or Empire in their official long name?

Tags: politics, near-future, names, royalty

I am writing a prospective that is set in a near future.

The United-Kingdom of Great-Britain and Northern-Ireland is now a republic, which means the British royal family has been abolished by a peaceful revolution. What I mean by a peaceful revolution is that members of the Windsor dynasty were not brutally killed by decapitation, there was just a referendum, and now, the Windsors are hidden among "normal" citizens. Nevertheless, like in the Fifth French Republic, there is still an aristocracy. However, this country still has the word Kingdom in their official long name.

So, I wonder why would a republic have a royalty-related word in their official long name.

Comment: What name is used for something is a function of choices made by politicians and the population as a whole, which makes this a story-based question.

Comment: The UK has, functionally, been a "republic" for a while now. The PRC has never been a "republic" at all.

Comment: Can you imagine how long it would take the UK to vote on a new name? It'd be worse than Brexit.

Comment: As a Native brit - I think the obvious answer is 'because we aren't the French'

Comment: @TheDemonLord I kept clicking the up button on your comment and was mightily disappointed that the number didn't go up. Just wanted you to know that.

Comment: @elemtilas:  PRC is a republic.  Republic simply means "The Head of State is not a position that is inherited."   The UK is still a monarchy because the King is the Head of State, even though it has a long history of representative democracy.   China is a Republic because when the current President of China dies, his eldest child does not become President of China, despite the fact that China is not a representative democracy.

Comment: @Cadence:  The UK changes it's name to Republicy McRepublic-Face.

Comment: Final note:   This has already happened before.  From 1649-1660, following the Second English Civil War, the nation was a Republic as "The Commonwealth of England."  A second republic era would likely change their name to the more modern "The Commonwealth of Great Britain and Northern Ireland."  Unfortunately, this will cause a lot of Americans to laugh if they follow with the more common name (UK) having a similar change (CW.  In the U.S., CW is a defunct TV Channel known for its programming block filled mostly with teen dramas.).

Comment: @hszmv Republic can mean other things, and it has meant other things through time and space. There's no reason you couldn't construe an hereditary republic, as absurd as that sounds.

Comment: @AmiralPatate The only other type of usage I've used is the American usage which is basically describing a representative democracy with an elected head of state as opposed to an inherited one.  The UK is a constitutional monarchy (the term used for a representative democracy with an inherited head of state).  The only other situation is North Korea... but that's weird (essentially the first President is still president even if he's dead... his son and now grandson are just keeping his office chair warm for him while he's away.  Not the best use of the case.).

Comment: @hszmv --- Not quite. A republic can in fact be a monarchy, and a man none other than John Adams considered the British Empire to be a republic. A republic requires that the people participate in the sovereignty, that it is a country of law and that the people participate in making and defending those laws. The UK could easily be seen as a "crowned republic". In the PRC, sovereignty lies with the Communist Party, not the people. You mention NK, and one could list any number of "republics" that are functional despotisms. Sovereignty subsists in the ruler. Constitutions are merely decorative.

Comment: @hszmv Kant: "Republicanism is the political principle of the separation of the executive power (the administration) from the legislative". Now, well, you know, that's just, like, his opinion, man, but it's certainly a definition you can take and run away with to justify a monarchic republic.

Comment: @AmiralPatate:  From Wikipedia:  "A republic (from Latin res publica 'public affair') is a state in which political power rests with the public and their representatives, in contrast with a monarchy."   What Kant is describing is Presidential or Semi-Presidential government.  In Constitutional Monarchies (Like the UK) the Prime Minister is the head of the administration of government as well as the legislature.   The King/Queen is a symbolic figure head who has very little political power.

Comment: @elemtilas:  Any read of poly-sci will tell you that a Republic does not rest on how the people determine leadership beyond it's not inherited like a monarchy.

Comment: @hszmv The point is that different people might define political concepts differently at different points in time. It's not inconceivable to have something called a Republic (or Kingdom), which was thus called in a time, place and set of circumstances when that made sense, and for that name to have never been changed even though the definition did.

Comment: @AmiralPatate And under current poli-science, the definition is not based on democratic institutions but rather on whether the head of state is a position passed on from a parent to a child OR if it's passed on through means that are not inheritance.  The association with democratic elections comes from the U.S. where it's quite common to use "Republic" to refer to "Representative Democracy."

Comment: It's very common for a country's official name to not represent its real political system. The usual example is the official name of North Korea - Democratic People's Republic of Korea. However, the word 'Kingdom' seems to be the exception to that - I can't think of a single example where a country is called a 'Kingdom' without having a monarchy, even purely symbolic one. If anyone knows an example, please correct me.

Comment: I just read a portal novel in which a knight from a feudal world is bewildered to learn that a County in Maryland has no Count.